# Change the last letter of place holder texts using css

Tags: css, placeholder

I have a place holder for Username.
Its placeholder text is "Enter you username *". **Here i want to change the color of * (star).**
I google but all the solution is using javascript or jquery but i want to make it working with CSS.

Anyone know how to do this using css ?

Thanks,
Aezaz

Comment: you cant target a single text of attribute using only CSS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes this is possible, Check this Question, But it will have `Browser Compatibility` issues

**[Working Fiddle for Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/HCHhL/1/)**

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder:after /* Only for Chrome */
{
   color:red;
   content:"*";
   opacity: 1
}
```

Read this;

[Style Placeholder Last Character with CSS](http://aamirshahzad.net/style-placeholder-last-character-with-css/)

good luck!

Comment: This does not longer works for some reason on Chrome in 2021.

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to style just the star part of the placeholder. check [this page](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder-css) out to style the placeholder using CSS

Alternatively you can use a absolutely position label/div with a span around the * then style the span.

Answer (score -3):

Code below is for placeholder

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: red;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: red;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: red;  
}
```

style only for *(star) is not..