# Change color of Place holder last character

Tags: html, css, placeholder

I have a form with `inputs` having `placeholders` showing `*` for required field in addition to helper text.

What i want is to change the color of `*` i.e. last character of placeholder

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name *" />
```

Is there any selectors for that?
In addition to below selector, selecting a `placeholder`;

`input::-webkit-input-placeholder` (for webkit browsers)

[image]

thanks in advance!

Comment: Nope you can't. Better wrap the input with some div, give to it `position: relative` and add a label with `position: absolute;` that way you can surround the `*` with span or something else. An you have to use js to hide the label on focus. The same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20964967/change-the-last-letter-of-place-holder-texts-using-css

Comment: @drip see ronan answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bit tricky, and you'll have to check yourself for the different browsers' support, but here is a <kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ronency/ucWAE/1/)</kbd> for you :-)

**html**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
```

**css**

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder:after{color:red;content:" *";}
```

Just moved the * to be a part of the :after element, and styled it separately.

Comment: It's not working. Could you please check your fiddle again?

Answer (score 2):

The top-rated solution doesn't work anymore
I found the solution from [How to set color for last character in placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41614440/how-to-set-color-for-last-character-in-placeholder)
And here is the code:

```
input {
  padding: 1em;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #AAA 0%, #AAA 70%,red 70%, red 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```